# How to upload files to OneDrive using Python OneDrive sdk?

Tags: python-3.x, onedrive

I am not able to get through the authentication successfully using Python OneDrive sdk. I can find examples for that with URLs, but I actually just want a code to upload files after authentication. No webpage is created by me for this purpose. In this case what should be my redirect URI?

Comment: I would say your answer is here: https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python

Comment: @progfou this SDK is deprecated.

Comment: @Tobonaut What's the supported way to interact with OneDrive via Python at the moment? Microsoft Graph API?

Comment: @scetoaux it seems that this is the way to go. But sometines the graph api requieres an Azure Active Directory.

Answer (score 3):

you need to set redirect http://localhost:8080/ in python and in onedrive app settings then after start browser windows will be opened in which you need press allow button.

[image]